# Naming a photo (date)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-photos

I am developing an app for andorid where I take pictures. The problem is that I only save cone l conseguidor current time in milliseconds and I want to put the current date (dd / mm / yyyy).

This is my code:

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() 
{
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try
        {               
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/mnt/extSdCard/Photos/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));    
    outStream.write(data);
    outStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        }

}
};
```

I tried to put this, but does not work I get error:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String day = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
String month = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
String year = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));

String name = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + ".jpg";
String folder = "/mnt/extSdCard/Photos/";
String path = folder + name;

...

outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(path));  
outStream.write(data);
outStream.close();
```

Can anyone help mep?

Comment: Where does the error occur? What is the error?

Comment: The debugger says something similar to the file doesn't exist

Comment: 02-26 15:55:54.117: W/System.err(10701): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/extSdCard/Potos/26/1/2013.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-26 15:55:54.117: W/System.err(10701):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-26 15:55:54.117: W/System.err(10701):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
02-26 15:55:54.117: W/System.err(10701):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
02-26 15:55:54.125: W/System.err(10701): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use '/' in filenames. That's interpreted by the system as a set of directories, and unless you've created all the directories ahead of time, you'll get this error. For example, if it's January 1, 2014, your filename will be:
/mnt/extSdCard/Photos/01/01/2014.jpg.

You need to either create the 01/01 directory, or change your separator to be something else, like '_' or '-'.

In addition, do not hardcode /mnt/extSdCard without at least a whitelist of devices to use it on. It does not exist on many, many devices, including all Nexus devices.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to use the code as follows:`code` String name = day + "-" + month + "-" + year + ".jpg"; I think that it would work. I've read in many web sites that is a bad practice to use hardcode, but in samsungs devices is impossible use evirotment or at least I have not found how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the folder string from Environment:

String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Photos/";

Then make sure Photos exists as a folder. Otherwise, you chould create it.

Comment: The function Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  is deprecated in android 4.0.4, this is not the problem because when i read files from external sd card i use as path "/mnt/extSdCard/" and it works

Comment: Do NOT use hardcoded paths. It will break on different Android devices. Use the Environment to retrieve writable directories.

Comment: By the way, I don't see that it's deprecated on the Android webpage: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: i say you thay this function don't works in devices that has sdcar as folder that internal memory y extSdCard as external memory, in developre can say this, but if yo read forums you read that hoy have to use hardcoded paths